# How to detect the presence of a given number in a string

Tags: php, string

I need to verify the presence of a number in a string. This is the code I had used:

```
$line='1';
$a=1;
echo strpos($line, $a);
if (strpos($line, 1) !== false) {
    echo 'ok';
}
```

I also tried this:

```
$line='1';
$a=1;
echo strpos($line, $a);
if (strpos($line, 1+'0') !== false) {
    echo 'ok';
}
```

In either case, however, it doesn't work.

Comment: I must be missing how the two ways are different.

Comment: Try `if(strpos($line, '1') !== false){` instead. Here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ca8fcbabf74b56eb553cac71bb82151365d405f5 (It doesn't show the "ok" part, so you can see the difference.)

Comment: i'm sorry i forgot the'0' in the second if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

> If **needle** is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character.

Since you're passing `1` as the `needle`, it's being converted to the character with that code, i.e. `Control-A`. So it's not looking for the digit `1` in the string. If you want to look for the character `1`, you have to use a character string, not an integer:

```
$a = '1';
echo strpos($line, $a);
if(strpos($line, '1') !== false) {
    echo 'ok';
}
```

If you're initially given a number, you can convert it to a string with `strval()`:

```
$a = 1;
$a = strval($a);
echo strpos($line, $a);
if(strpos($line, $a) !== false) {
    echo 'ok';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The strpos works on strings. If you do this

```
$line='1234';
$a='1';
echo strpos($line, '1');
if(strpos($line, '1') !== false){
    echo 'ok';
}
```

or

```
$line='1234';
$a='1';
echo strpos($line, $a);
if(strpos($line, $a) !== false){
    echo 'ok';
}
```

It will work

Answer (score 1):

strpos takes three arguments where third argument is optional i.e
`strpos(string,find,start)`. Here find should be of string type if it is not of string type then it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character. Means it takes its ascii value character. For eg.

```
$string="ABC";
$find=65;
$pos=strpos($string,$find);
echo $pos

Output:
0
```

i.e position of character 'A' because 65 is an ASCII value of 'A' character.
So when you passed integer value 1 to the `strpos` function it is converted to some ASCII character and it will return false in your case.
It might be possible that `strpos` function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. So, use the `===` operator for testing the return value of this function.

To work your code fine you have to convert the integer type to string type.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the php function [`ord()`](http://php.net//manual/es/function.ord.php), and check if the number is in the range of a `ASCII` for the numbers.